# intellisense in VS2015 never ends

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

We have project in VisualStudio2015 (C++) with 6000+ files. We encountered problem with intellisense. It is parsing files and never ends. For this reason I can't close Visaul Studio.

I find out that process `Microsoft (R) Visual C++ Package Server` `vcpkgsrv.exe` is probably in infinite loop. When I kill it I am able to close also VS.

I turned on diagnostic logging for intellisense and i can see these lines in output window.

```
[WorkItem] >> [NowQ] WorkerThreadAsync:Optimize QuickSearch Cache
[WorkItem] >> [NowQ] WorkerThreadAsync:Optimize QuickSearch Cache
[WorkItem] >> [NowQ] WorkerThreadAsync:Optimize QuickSearch Cache
[WorkItem] >> [NowQ] WorkerThreadAsync:Optimize QuickSearch Cache
```

And it never finish.

In another project I can see (which works fine)

```
[WorkItem] >> [NowQ] WorkerThreadAsync:Optimize QuickSearch Cache
[WorkItem] .  [NowQ] WorkerThreadAsync:Optimize QuickSearch Cache
[WorkItem] +  [NowQ] WorkerThreadAsync:Optimize QuickSearch Cache (0ms)
```

I would guess that this operation is added, executed and done.
And in my broken project it is only added and never executed.

Does anybody know what could be problem?

**Edit:** This problem occurs after Update2

Comment: Are you sure it *never* ends, or just takes a long time because you have 6000+ files in a single project? (Is it really a single *project*, or do you mean a single *workspace* with multiple projects?)

Comment: Try close Visual Studio, then remove `VC.db` file and `ipch` folder, then open your project again. VS will rebuild IntelliSense information.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude One solution with three projects. One is main other are only small for support. I don't know how to count all files because not all includes are in project. I just count *.h, *.c, *.cpp in solution folder.

Comment: @MartinZhai It didn't help. It was different. After I started it again it was fine but when I opened one file with lot of includes it takes some time to process it and then again never ending `[WorkItem] >> [NowQ] WorkerThreadAsync:Optimize QuickSearch Cache`

Comment: @elanius, now the latest update is VS 2015 update 3, you can go to Tools-Extensions and Updates-Updates to download the VS 2015 update 3 to install, then check this issue. Have you tried to reload or clean up this broken solution, or delete the .suo or .vs file under the project store folder to troubleshot this issue.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT I already have Update3. Just to be sure I did new clone of my project (no generated files were downloaded). And it is same. It is fine until I open any file which contains includes.

Comment: @elanius, you can have a try with run the command: devenv /resetuserdata, /safemode, /resetsettings to troubleshot the VS factors, or go to Control Panel-Programs and Features and right click the VS 2015 to repair. It looks like this issue only happens to the files that contains #includes in this broken project and for other projects, the similar files work fine, right?

Comment: @Sara-MSFT Whoever clone this solution will have this problem in our team. It happened after Update2 and continues also in Update3. I am almost sure that it is bug in intellisense but I don't know how to locate it. If there would be another diagnostic tool it could help.

Comment: What would be correct microsoft site for reporting such bug?

Comment: @elanius, if this project works fine before you installed the update 2 or 3, you can raise up this issue on this: https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with certain code. Had to manually kill `vcpkgsrv.exe` every now and then – e.g., when changing from Debug build to Release or vice versa. Otherwise Visual Studio would just stay frozen forever.

Solution:

```
#ifndef __INTELLISENSE__

... the code causing the trouble ...

#endif // __INTELLISENSE__
```

In my case, it was sufficient to add this in exactly one `.cpp` file. Your mileage may vary, of course.

Note that there's two consecutive underscores both in the beginning and in the end.

Comment: We already moved to VS2017 and there it works. But either we don't know which part of code was responsible for it.